# API 0x can't swap and swap back ? i got many to fail

Tags: 0x

[image: transaction fail at debug]

there is not support ?
i sent them 1 transaction from smart contact

```
fillQuote(
        token1,
        token2,
        uint256(_sellAmount),
        address(_allowanceTarget),
        payable(_to),
        _data1
    );

    uint256 _afterBalance = token2.balanceOf(address(this));

    uint256 _toAmount = _afterBalance - _beforeBalance;
    require(_toAmount > 0, "swap back token not enough");

    fillQuote(
        token2,
        token1,
        uint256(_toAmount),
        address(_allowanceTarget),
        payable(_to),
        _data2
    );
```

https://polygonscan.com/tx/0xd503b6720fccd8b9d9d90794f47d7d765ce86d2910877839fbc892b224d8655c

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide more information on what you are doing?

Firstly make sure there are allowances on both `token1` and `token2`. Secondly your first trade may get a different amount than what is encoded in `_data2`, so it might be equal to or higher than the second quote (which I assume is `_data2`)

Comment: yes now im trying with flashloan my code worked 10:100 success rate 

my code in fillQuote here :

Comment: require(sellToken.approve(spender, sellAmount), "go approve IERC20");

        (bool success, ) = swapTarget.call{value: msg.value}(swapCallData);
        require(success, "SWAP_CALL_FAILED");

        require(sellToken.approve(spender, 0), "RESET TOKEN");

Comment: If you're arbitraging you will have to both make a profit and pay back your flash loan.

It's extremely difficult to debug your query with just this information.

0xAPI has been used successfully with atomic arbitrage in the past but the game has since moved on and it is no longer practical.